# Mongodb or Memcached on busy site?

Tags: mongodb, memcached

My system have a huge connections and data read and write always. I installed Memcached (only one memcached)but failed because a large connections and I tried to install Mongodb (only one instance too) but still failed.

My data is not large (about > 10.000 records). Now I'm using MySQL but it's very slow.

I'm thinking about memcached replication and master/slave on mongodb! Which one should i choice?

Thank you very much!

(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: "a large connections " means what exactly?

Comment: Did you check your database, try to optimize queries, add index? Do you have an exemple of data?

Comment: @Blackmoon: "a large connections" means simultaneous connections to my server (~12.000 connections).

Comment: @Brice Favre: My database is very simple. This is my example:
   "zone_id": 3376,
   "zone_data": <sample-data>,
   "zone_update": 0

zone_id is primary key. My queries only "select zone_data where zone_id = ''" and sometimes I run a cront to update zone_update to 1. If connections < 11.000 everything is ok but if connections > 12.000 database server is very slow.

Comment: Hi Tuan, it would help if you could give some context to what your site is doing with the connections.  Are they all accessing the DB?  If so, what are they accessing and when.  It would also help if you say what technology you are using to construct your website as the web components may be as much of a part as the DB.

Comment: Hi Sean, i'm building a tool to manage rich media advertisement for my company (have some websites with large users). When the page load, I get data from DB and render to page.
I used PHP, MySQL to built the tool. I have only one server for this tool :(. Server OS is CentOS running Apache, PHP 5.2 and My-SQL 5.5.8.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is not likely to be causing your site to run slowly, especially with the amount of data you mention.  I would stick with MySQL and try to find what is causing your site to run slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Try running EXPLAIN on your MySql queries to know what is going wrong...